# How to decode and output the following code (ex. \u00e8, \u00e9) in the format of a string to their symbols in Python

Tags: javascript, python, encoding, beautifulsoup, decoding

I am currently doing a Python Web Scraping project. Something that I am scraping saves symbols like `é`, `à` and other symbols (ex. Cyrillic) as codes like `\u00e8`, `\u00e9`. I am using BeautifulSoup to format whatever I get from the web and save it as a string. However I want to output the symbols to a file, not in the encoded format but as their actual symbols (ex. `é`). How can you decode the string so that I can output the symbols to file?

Comment: You may find this helpful http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Answer (score 2):

You can decode such strings like this:

```
 >> s = '\u00e8'

 >> x = s.decode('unicode_escape')

 >> print x
   è
 >> type(x)
   unicode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the characters to strings using the str() builtin function passing the character as argument

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I am reading these characters as the codes like '\u00e8' and I want to convert them back to the characters when I output them to file.